# Problems with 2 relationships between 2 tables in the same column under Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, activerecord, foreign-key-relationship

I have a doubt, Im making a friend's platform on a Ruby on Rails site; I have a table called **users**, and a table called **friends** that manages the friendships between the users. In **friends** I have 2 fields, *user_id1* and *user_id2*. This is the relationship I made in the models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :friends
end
```

```
class Friend < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => "user_id1"
    belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => "user_id2"
end
```

Is this a good way to handle this situation? Another idea is create another model that points to the same table in the database, **userAux**, and use it for the relationship. What do you think is best? Do you have a better idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

A self-referencing many-to-many structure is often called a Bill of Materials.  It is a very good idea, and quite commonly used in Relational databases.  Here is the [**Data Model**](http://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Student%20Resolutions/pablo89%20DM.pdf).  You would have boolean attributes such as `IsAccepted` and `IsRejected`.

Please do not name the columns as `user_id1, 2`.  Please call them something that is actually meaningful, such `host_id` and `guest_id` or `requester_id` and `friend_id`.  The relevance of that will only become clear when you are coding.

Readers who are unfamiliar with the Relational Modelling Standard may find [**IDEFIX Notation**](http://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Documentary%20Examples/IDEF1X%20Notation.pdf) useful.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a very similar situation referenced here: http://oldwiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/HowToCreateASelfReferentialManyToManyRelationship